# Extract multiple OSM-types with osmfilter and ONE command

Tags: openstreetmap, geofabrik, osmfilter

I use osmfilter to extract specific parts of raw geodata retrieved from [geofabrik.de](https://www.geofabrik.de). Let's say for my spatial analysis I like to get all buildings, farmlands, meadows and nationalparks.

I do not want to write the same command for osmfilter four times `[...] --keep= [...]`

Is there a way to do this with one command but still get the four differnt files ?

Comment: (not an answer to a question about osmfilter but) today I'd probably use the capabilities of [osmium](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html) to do this sort of thing.  See the examples at https://github.com/SomeoneElseOSM/Boundary_Scripts/blob/master/update_boundaries.sh#L174 and below (not exactly what you want, but an example of "what tasks to perform" in an external lua file).